# How are implementations of standard library header files function prototypes are written in c++?

Tags: c++, function, header

I know that C++ has a standard library which consists of header files which consists of functions prototypes but where are their implementations? I mean I want to see how `cout << "hey";` really works. How are implementations of built in functions are written? in assembly?

Comment: "_How are implementations of built in functions are written?_" Since most of STL, is header-only (that I am aware of), did you try looking through the directory, where you installed the compiler?

Comment: Most of STL classes are class templates. Their implementations are in the corresponding header files.

Comment: Technically, it is up to the implementation.    For templated functions and classes (a large part of the C++ standard library) the definitions are - more often than not - in the corresponding header file, or in a file `#include`d by that header.

Comment: Beware that standard library implementations are usually very hard to read. In addition, the language makes allowances for compiler and standard library implementers which you, as a developer, cannot make use of. Finally, those implementers don't have to be portable as they typically target specific platforms. This means that they may do things that are otherwise illegal in c++ or that may not behave as expected on other platforms, meaning you that what you learn from standard library implementations may not necessarily be true of c++ in general.

Answer (score 4):

The burden of implementing the C++ standard library can be discharged in any way so long as the specification is respected. In other words if you `#include` the requisite header, then you get the function you want.

Much of it is indeed written in C++ and you can view the code with your line-by-line debugger if your compiler toolset ships with the standard library source code. One problem with reading the standard library code is that any variable needs to be one that can't be `#define`d as a macro by a programmer. Which is why the variable names are prefixed with `__` or `_` followed by an upper case letter.

Some of this C++ may well have constructs that are non-portable since a C++ standard library implementation is typically tied to the compiler. Indeed some functions (e.g. `std::malloc`) cannot be written in standard C++!

Some components of the library may well be written in assembler (e.g. `std::strlen`) or perhaps even hardcoded into the compiler itself.